# Calculate value from criteria in row and column title

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I got problem in excel. I have this source table

[image: Source Table]

And i want to fill below table with the sum value based on criteria on related column & row.

[image: Result Table]

Please help. Using sumif is so much work, because i have many tables that i need to fill. I believe there will be much better way than that.

I dont know whether an array formula by using MATCH, INDEX & INDIRECT could solve this.

Comment: Based on *what* criteria?

Comment: Based on value on each cell header (row and column). For example, in cell #1 in the result table, the criteria will be 'Def' and '2016'.

Comment: Thanks pnuts. Are there any other options? Like an array INDEX, MATCH & INDIRECT solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS IS AN ARRAY FORMULA -**

**WHILE STILL IN THE FORMULA BAR USE <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>**

`{=SUM(IF($A$3:$A$7=B$9,IF($B$2:$K$2=$A10,$B$3:$K$7)))}`

As this is an array formula, the IF statements build separate arrays of TRUE/FALSE and assess the output against the array of values, returning either FALSE or the value as another array... Sum is then totalling this array and as it only works for true values it is ignoring the FALSE outputs in the array:

```
=SUM(IF({TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE},
IF({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE},
$B$3:$K$7)))
```

[image]

```
=SUM({0,FALSE,0,FALSE,0,FALSE,119.6,FALSE,51.4,FALSE;
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE; 
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE})
```

Notice how the array recognises each row and assigns a semi-colon as opposed to a comma.

Comment: Already trying it, but value 171 shows on every cell in result table. As if the array only copying the result from cell #1. I dont know how to upload my image's result.

Comment: Use imgbb to share my result. This is the link
[link](https://image.ibb.co/jrou2F/result2.jpg)

Comment: @y2a Have you dragged the formula across using the bottom right of the cell? It looks like the exact same formula is in every cell. References need to be updated. The placement of the '$'s in my formula allow for formula dragging...

Comment: For example in `C10` should be `{=SUM(IF($A$3:$A$7=C$9,IF($B$2:$K$2=$A10,$B$3:$K$7)))}` as the column has now moved and we are no longer looking for `"Def"`

Comment: Oh i see. It worked now Glitch_Doctor.
My first way was creating a range to all cells in range table. Type the formula and Ctrl+Shift+Enter. I didnt know i got to drag the formula.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah dragging is the easiest option, either that or manually update the reference cell each time (or even worse, build in an `INDIRECT()` clause using `Row()` and `Column()`). Glad it worked out for you... Thank you for accepting my answer.